# Request to increase Android Management API device limit

Tags: android-management-api

I am working for a non-profit organization with more than 2,500 employees and as many android smartphones.

We have tested many EMM products in recent years. Even though we only need a few very basic features, aside from one or two special functionalities, none of them has really won us over.
Most of them either just don’t work properly, lack essential features, have poor support or are just extremely expensive.

However, we have a very capable development team and after studying and testing Googles Android Management API we believe the best way to solve our problem is to develop a solution on our own.

The thing is we do not intent to sell this product to anyone. We just want to use it within our company.

According to Googles [Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/android/work/release-solution) you have to join the Android Enterprise EMM Provider community if you want to increase the default usage limit beyond 1,000 devices.
Since we don’t intent to sell our software, and as an NPO, we have no interest in becoming an official EMM Provider (also, it is probably impossible).

Therefore my question: Is it allowed to use the Android Management API for such a purpose and is there a way to increase the default usage limit for our project without becoming an official EMM Provider?

I was not able to find an answer to that in Google’s official documentation, on stackoverflow, or anywhere else. Apparently, there should be a support team for every available API. So normally, I would just ask Google myself. The problem with that is that I don’t know how to get in contact with them.

I have tried to send a request to the support on Google Cloud Platform, but they told me that they are only able to give support for the Google Maps Platform.

The [Support Page](https://developers.google.com/android/management/feedback) of the Android Management API only refers to stackoverflow, which is why I am asking here.

We are really looking forward to doing this project. It would be such a shame if we would have to cut it off. I hope someone here can lead me in the right direction.

So, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you should indeed be able to ask for AM API quotas increase from the cloud console under Android Management API. Have you tried submitting the request through the form bellow: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe71rO7BLw5hkB6__uKZxDXnA5LUZtI0-g43vmkYY3rLoC0fA/viewform?

However, am afraid that you can only request quotas for user operations per second (1000 qps per default) and what you're looking for in terms of device management seems like you will need indeed to join the EMM Provider community. You could possibly discuss with your Google Sales Rep point of contact (I suppose you might have one) but I don't believe you'll be able to bypass joining the EMM provider community. It doesn't necessarily mean that you'll have to become an official EMM provider but the community element I believe is a requirement.

Sorry, I realise it might not be the answer you're looking for but hopefully it helps a bit.